# loading grub boot loader

Tags: grub2, opensuse

I am trying to install a dual boot on my system. I have windows8.1 installed and I am installing opensuse13.2. I restart my system, go to the boot menu and start my installation from my CD drive.

opensuse boot loader doesn't shows up, instead I get GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta2. It gives a list of commands that I can type. I don't know how to start the boot loader to start the installation for opensuse13.2. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you have another non-Windows system installed before? Windows doesn't include GRUB of course, so if you see it, it must come from the openSUSE install CD and you should be able to continue. What is included in the "list of commands"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UEFI Secure boot mode needs to be turned off, otherwise it will stop grub loader from loading. Once the secure boot mode is turned off, the grub2 loader begins automatically.